# How to upgrade MS SQL Server from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a production server, that is used for MS SQL Server Databases.

The machine specs are:
 - Intel Xeon E5410 CPU with (EM64T)
 - 4 GB RAM
 - SCSI HDDs in RAID mode

It currently has:
 - Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 2 (32bit)
 - SQL Server 2005 (9.0.3080) (32 bit) as the default instance.
 - SQL Server 2008 (10.0.1600) (32 bit) as a named instance "SQL2008".

I need to upgrade the SQL Server 2008 instance to 64 bit. 
How do I do this?

I know that the OS needs to be 64 bit mode too. Can I do a upgrade of windows to Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit first or?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll basically need to make a back up of the existing databases, then rebuild the server using Windows Server 2008 R2 and install SQL Server 2008 x64.  Windows doesn't support changes in the bit-ness of the OS when performing an upgrade; no 32 bit upgrades to 64 bit.